# array or list in C# with custom key?

Tags: c#, arrays

is it possible to make an array or a list or something equal with a custon integer key?

e.g.
I want to have an array of size 3 but not with the default keys 0,1,2 but with custon keys like: 100,302,502

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

```
var dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dic.Add(100, 35);
dic.Add(302, 45);
dic.Add(502, 55);
Console.WriteLine(dic[100]);
Console.WriteLine(dic[502]);
```

This will output 35 and 55.

You can also run a `foreach` over the dictionary, but since it's a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), it won't necessarily be in order. Also, while the performance is constant time (i.e. won't be too much slower even if the dictionary gets really big), it *is* somewhat slower than an array.

**Edit**: By the way, you can also use different kinds of values for the key and/or value. For instance, you can say something like:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, double>;
dic.Add("hot dogs", 3.99);
Console.WriteLine(dic["hot dogs"]);
```

And it'll print `3.99`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Dictionary<T>` or HashTable.

Comment: Dictionary has 2 generic types, TKey and TValue ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a 2 dimensional array.